# Open by default column three or any other in draglist(Woxblom)android

Tags: android, kotlin

i am using https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView (Woxblom) lib,i have a trouble while open dragList. i want to open by default column number three after setting all columns , is it possible.....?
can someone help is appreciated in advance

i have try this after adding all columns  but it could not open specified column

```
    private fun resetBoard(
    oldColumn: Int, oldRow: Int, newColumn: Int, isDraggable: Boolean,
) {
    binding.boardView.clearBoard()
    binding.boardView.setCustomDragItem(MyDragItem(activity, R.layout.column_item))
    binding.boardView.setCustomColumnDragItem(MyDragItem(activity, R.layout.column_drag_layout))


    if (isDraggable) {
        if (mDraftItemArray.size > oldRow) {

            if (oldRow == 0) {
                mDraftItemArray[oldRow].second.topMargin = true
            } else if (!mDraftItemArray[oldRow].second.itemIdSort.equals(
                    mDraftItemArray[oldRow - 1].second.itemIdSort,
                    true
                )
            ) {
                mDraftItemArray[oldRow].second.topMargin = true
            }
        }

        if (newColumn == ColumnStatus.Inprogress.column || oldColumn == ColumnStatus.Todo.column) {
            updateRowItems(mToDoItemArray)
        }
        if (newColumn == ColumnStatus.Inprogress.column || oldColumn == ColumnStatus.Inprogress.column) {
            updateRowItems(mInProgressItemArray)
        }
        if (newColumn == ColumnStatus.ForApproval.column || oldColumn == ColumnStatus.ForApproval.column) {
            updateRowItems(mForApprovalItemArray)
        }
        if (newColumn == ColumnStatus.Completed.column || oldColumn == ColumnStatus.Completed.column) {
            updateRowItems(mCompletedItemArray)
        }
    }
    addColumn(mDraftItemArray)
    addColumn(mToDoItemArray)
    addColumn(mInProgressItemArray)
    addColumn(mForApprovalItemArray)
    addColumn(mCompletedItemArray)


   binding.boardView.scrollToColumn(2,true)


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({

        binding.boardView.scrollToColumn(2, true)
                                                },500)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**